# garbage values while dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

My code for dynamically allocating arrays, even though the Input methods for both arrays `pattern` and `text` are same `text` outputs different values, can anyone solve this issue?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int length=5;
    int * pattern = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int * text = malloc(length * sizeof(int));  
    int pattern_size=0;
    int text_size=0;
    printf("Enter Pattern:");

    char c; 
    while(c != '$' && scanf("%c",&c) != '\n'){ 
        if(pattern_size >= length)
            pattern = realloc(pattern, (length += 10) * sizeof(int));
        if(c!=',') pattern[pattern_size] = atoi(&c)+pattern[pattern_size]*10;
        else if(c==',') {
            pattern_size++;
        }
        
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter the replacement text:");
    // get_array(text,&text_size,length);

    char d; 
    while(d != '$' && scanf("%c",&d) != '\n'){ 
        if(text_size >= length)
            text = realloc(text, (length += 10) * sizeof(int));
        if(d!=',') text[text_size] = atoi(&d)+text[text_size]*10;
        else if(d==',') {
            text_size++;
        }
        
    }

    for(int i=0;i<pattern_size; i++){
        printf("%d ",pattern[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<text_size; i++){
        printf("%d ",text[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
Input
Enter Pattern:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,$
Please enter the replacement text:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,$
OUTPUT
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 10417 8 540155953 540287027
```

Comment: `scanf("%c",&d) != '\n'` - `scanf` returns the number of specifiers converted, not the character values.

Comment: Also `d != '$'` and  `d != '$'`  are done when `d` and `c` are uninitialized. Probably other things too, and you might be getting a bunch of warnings that you have ignored.

Comment: @could you please suggest something to make my code work

Comment: Start with fixing the issues I have pointed to. Look through compiler output and fix the warnings. Debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should ever check the return value of `malloc` and `scanf`.
2. `Scanf` does not return the element scanned. Please check `man 3 scanf`

> On success, these functions return the number of input  items
> success‐    fully  matched  and  assigned;  this can be fewer than
> provided for, or    even zero, in the event of an early matching
> failure.    The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached
> before  either    the  first  successful conversion or a matching
> failure occurs.  EOF is    also returned if a read error occurs, in
> which case the error indicator    for the stream (see ferror(3)) is
> set, and errno is set to indicate the    error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int length = 1;
    int *pattern = calloc(length, sizeof(int));
    if (pattern == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find free memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int* text = calloc(length, sizeof(int)); 
    if (text == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find free memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int pattern_size = 0;
    int text_size = 0;
    printf("Enter Pattern:\n");
    char c = ' '; 
    while (c != '$') { 
        if (scanf("%c", &c) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in scanf\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (isdigit(c) != 0) {
            pattern[pattern_size] = c - 48;
            pattern_size++;
            pattern = realloc(pattern, (pattern_size + 1) * sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    printf("\nPlease enter the replacement text:\n");
    // get_array(text,&text_size,length);
    char d = ' '; 
    while (d != '$') { 
        if (scanf("%c", &d) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in scanf\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (isdigit(d) != 0) {
            text[text_size] = d - 48;
            text_size++;
            text = realloc(text, (text_size + 1) * sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\nOUTPUT:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern_size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", pattern[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < text_size; i++)
        printf("%d ", text[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
    free(pattern);
    free(text);
}
```

Including `ctype.h` you canuse the library function `int isdigit(char c)` that take in input a `char` and tells you if it is a number between 0 and 9.

Comment: Didn't solve the issue, getting ```1 2 3 4 5 6 10417 8 540155953 540287027``` as output for ```text``` array for Input ```1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,$```

Comment: @anfjnini Sorry, i have not modified length, now i edited it, and it works, the problem was length that was too short.

Comment: @anfjnini length must be biggerr than the number of input elements.

Comment: the point of dynamic allocation is to overcome this issue, in the case when the size of the ```length``` is less than the size of ```input``` we dynamically allocate memory, but that's not the case in the above code. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @anfjnlnl malloc and calloc is dynamic allocation. Ok, realloc too but you must explain better your problem. You want to allocate a small array and then realloc it every time?

Comment: yes, I want to allocate a small array and then realloc it every time

Comment: @anfjnlnl I edited the code using initial length as 1 and reallocating it every time, i hope now is good! Tell me if there is something you don't understand.